# How to write a workdays_between function as table function in SAP HANA?

Tags: hana-sql-script

How to calculate workdays_between function for begin date and end date of a table in SAP HANA?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the function should return amount of weekdays? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The usage of workdays_between is as follows:

```
select
    WORKDAYS_BETWEEN('01', '2017-11-01', '2017-11-30' , 'SAPABAP1') as number_of_workdays 
from dummy;
```

If you have date ranges stored in a database table, then you can use following query as sample

```
select
    WORKDAYS_BETWEEN('01', date_begin, date_end, 'SAPABAP1') as number_of_workdays 
from date_ranges;
```

Please note that here the schema name SAPABAP1 is where the TFACS table is created

I hope it helps